# Undertow Access Log issue

Tags: logging, undertow

I am facing a strange problem with respect to access log. The messages in the access log are showing partially correct when I run the application as a jar. However when I debug the application in the IDE I do not see this problem.

I am using Undertow and its AccessLogHandler as follows -

`Undertow.builder().setHandler(new AccessLogHandler(new RequestLimitingHandler(new RequestLimit(1000, 1000),`
`getRestEasyServlet(config)),`
                        `new Slf4jAccessLogReceiver(LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.pkg.logging")),`
    `"combined", Server.class.getClassLoader()))`

```
package com.pkg.logging;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.AccessLogReceiver;

public class Slf4jAccessLogReceiver implements AccessLogReceiver {
    private final Logger logger;

    public Slf4jAccessLogReceiver(final Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void logMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

The following are the messages when i run this app as a jar -

`2020-03-05 15:40:31,298 INFO [XNIO-1 task-1] class=logging %h %l %u %t "POST /entities/176ce8d1-ded8-3cbd-b18a-bfb3c0a7b1ea HTTP/1.1" %s %b "%{i,Referer}" "%{i,User-Agent}"`

`2020-03-05 15:40:41,625 INFO [XNIO-1 task-2] class=logging %h %l %u %t "POST /entities/176ce8d1-ded8-3cbd-b18a-bfb3c0a7b1ea HTTP/1.1" %s %b "%{i,Referer}" "%{i,User-Agent}"`

As I said when I run the same server code from an IDE and notice the logs I do not see this issue.

The following are the lib versions I am using -

```
compile group: 'io.undertow', name: 'undertow-core', version: '2.0.14.Final'
compile group: 'io.undertow', name: 'undertow-servlet', version: '2.0.14.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.6.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
```

JDK - 11

The following is the log4j2 file -

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPath">${env:logPath:-/home/}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="File" fileName="${logPath}/yjava_jetty.out"
                                 filePattern="${logPath}server-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout alwaysWriteExceptions="false">
                <Pattern>\{"t":"%d","l":"%p","th":"%t","cl":"%c{1}",%m%enc{%throwable{100}}{JSON}"\}%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="AccessLog" fileName="${logPath}/access"
                                 filePattern="${logPath}/access-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <!--<Pattern>%d %p [%t] class=%c{1} %m%throwable{10}%n</Pattern>-->
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy  max="4">
                <Delete basePath="${logPath}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="access-*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="4h" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.pkg.logging" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AccessLog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="io.undertow.request.dump" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AccessLog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you tried using the `io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver`?

Comment: no I have not. Lemme check.

Comment: Checked with JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver. I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: The only other difference I see is in the debug log. I see the following msg with 2 nulls in the debug log when I run the jar file - 
DEBUG null null initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/path/api.jar!/log4j2.xml]

Comment: So for some reason it looks like the logs are not being formatted. I'm not really sure what would cause that. What you're doing looks correct to me.